# Usage of "first" without "second"

Tags: word-usage

My question is about my contract at work. My employer started providing us with an "on call" phone for the week we are on call to contact us in case of emergency call-ins. For the past  20 years they would call us in via cell phone or home phone. In the contract it says that the phone provided will be contacted "first". They have my personal cell phone number on file, which they use during the day to reach me. They also use my personal cell phone to call me in if they need an extra person to help the on-call crew. However, the management says that the phone provided by them will be the "only" phone contacted to call in the emergency crew. Again, the contract says the provided phone will be called "first". Can you use the word "first" and there not be a "second"? Especially if they have a second number on file? I was just wondering if there was a grammar rule on this. Thank you for any help.

It is written exactly like this:

> EMERGENCY CALL IN.  Designated employees required to be on Stand-By will have a cell phone provided so that Supervision can contact them while on call. The cell phone will be the first number called.

Since they have my personal cell phone number also, I take this to mean that they would call my number second. Now Management is saying that the provided cell phone is the only phone they will call. Ironically, if I don't answer the provided phone, they move on to the next guy by calling his personal phone. I basically was wondering if grammatically you use the word "first", that there should be at least a "second".

Comment: Not sure what you see as a problem here. "First" means first, and it's implicit in using this ordinal number that there may be subsequent occasions. There's no need to state a "second" arrangement. If you accept the meaning but want to challenge the legality of the practice under your contract, I'm afraid our EL&U site is not the place to ask. :-)

Comment: Please provide the actual text of the contract. We would need to see at least the full sentence where this usage of *first* occurs, and preferably the full paragraph. Also please provide the relevant section of the communication you've received from the management. Details of phrasing, the context—they all matter.

Comment: Thank you for providing the text containing the word *first*. Is there no corresponding text from the management, maybe in an email? Or was it all oral? Is there nothing official? If there isn't anything official, how do you actually know that the management 'will move on to the next guy by calling his personal phone'? (Also, you don't really mean 'his **personal** phone', correct? You mean the 'on call' phone he was provided with, right?)

Comment: What I wrote is how it is written in our contract word for word. If the on call person does not answer within 10 minutes, they lose their on call status and management moves on to the next guy at that position. There is only one person on call at each position. There is only one on call phone for each position, so the only way to contact the next man up is to call his personal phone.

Comment: OK, now I understand about the personal phone. But aside from the part that you highlighted (i.e. this text: *EMERGENCY CALL IN. Designated employees required...*), nothing else looks like a direct quote. Can you give a **direct quote** where it says that if the on-call person does not answer within 10 min then... etc.? And put it as a highlighted quote?

Comment: But preliminarily: when they say that the on-call phone will be 'the first number called', this does normally imply that there should also be a second number called. But it is possible that this second number will be someone else's number.

Comment: I agree that, given the context, the natural reading would be that 'the numbers' they are talking about in that quote refers to the various phone numbers that the on-call person has. If they wanted to say these will be some other people's numbers, they should have phrased it better. Having said all that, however: **strictly speaking,** the highlighted text is **not** inconsistent with the fact that the (implied) second number dialed will be someone else's number, rather than an alternate number of the on-call person.

Comment: I take it as there is a second number and that it should be my personal phone, since I am the only one who is on call in that position for that week. Managements stance seems to be that "first" means only...

Comment: I agree that this is the most natural reading. But consider it from the perspective of the person making the call. He or she just dials numbers. The first number they dial is the number of the on-call phone. If that fails, they will dial a second number. No matter how this second number is determined, it's still the second number they will dial.

Comment: Good point, but for the past 20 years they've called the on call guys personal phone, whether it was a home phone or cell phone. When I had both a home phone and a cell phone, they would call my home phone first, and if there was no answer, they'd call my cell phone second.